# Automated testing of multi-client workflows with Selenium

Tags: selenium, mobile, web, automation, automated-tests

I'm trying to automate some test cases with Selenium WebDriver.
My problem is that most test cases need interactions from different devices.
An example:

- Mobile App (Android or iOS) initiates a new workflow
- Desktop user has to approve it
- Mobile user can now continue with the workflow
- Desktop user can continuously see at which step the mobile user currently is

Is is possible to create Selenium Tests that can test these interactions?
If yes, how?